# What is the best way to make use of numerical variables together with text mining for classification purposes?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, text-mining

I have a document-term matrix and I was able to classify the documents into their respective classes using svm.

Now, I have numerical variables associated with the documents which I think might improve my classification model further. Eg, think of tweets, comprising their text content as well as the date stamp, number of retweets, number of replies n other metadata etc.

What is the best way to make use of the numerical variables, in combination with the DTM, to create my classification model?

A few ways I can think of (but not sure if they are the best/correct way).

1) 
Simply merge the DTM with the dataset that contains the numerical variables and then perform svm. In R, this will be to cbind the DTM and the numVarsMatrix, re-create the container n then create the model: 
train_model(container,"SVM",..)

2) 
Use ensemble methods to combine the ML model on the DTM with an ML model on the numerical dataset.